# How I use Selenium for testing in the Safari browser?

Tags: python, selenium

How I use Selenium for testing in the Safari browser?
When I run Selenium on Safari, the following popup comes and stops Selenium.
How I prevent this popup?

[image: POPUP]

The error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
```

I add this.

```
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()

alert.accept()
```

but another popup stops the session.
I can't click "Continue Session" even manual.

[image: added photo]

Comment: Have you can tried "webdriver.switch_to_alert()" method, then "accept()"?

Comment: Thank you I did. but one more popup came in and it stops the test. I add photo.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/testing_with_webdriver_in_safari